# Multiple setOnAction cleanup in JavaFX and stopping the application after 5 questions

Tags: java, javafx, code-cleanup

I'm trying to create an application where a word will appear in the middle and depending on how well a person pronounces it a score will be added. Each button will increment the question number by 1 and add a score equal to their face values of 0 - 5. 6 buttons with `setOnAction` consisting of 9 lines each is quite a lot to be put into the `start()` method so I've tried shoving them into another method and using that.

But while testing, the question number nor the score value increments. Additionally, there's a limit of 5 questions and I am stumped trying to work it out. I've tried using while loops, do-while loops, for loops, while-for loops, and googling around for similar situations and trying their solutions but I still couldn't get it to stop after 5.

I'm using JavaFX for this application and have studied Java for 2 semesters. I'd appreciate any advice.

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private int qn;
    private Button b0 = new Button("Next");
    private Text t = new Text();
    private HBox tP = new HBox();
    private HBox bP = new HBox();
    private BorderPane p = new BorderPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        qn = 1;
        boolean finish = false;
        Label labeltop = new Label("Question " + qn + ":");
        b0.setMaxSize(50, 25);
        b0.setOnAction((e) -> {
            qn++;
            labeltop.setText("Question " + qn + ":");
        });
        tP.getChildren().add(labeltop);
        bP.getChildren().addAll(b0);
        p.setTop(tP);
        p.setBottom(bP);
        p.setCenter(t);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(p));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: ```score += 0;``` literally does nothing.

Comment: I'll go and remove that. Don't know what I was thinking when I wrote it

Comment: one problem per question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected. Mind the __M__! Nothing more than the bare bones to show the problem .. in your case - and taking the doesn't-stop-at-5 - that's just a single button, no ui decorations, no calls to external code in the action handlers. That said: you are missing a condition when to stop (best bind the button's disabled to a boolean property representing the max-answers-reached state, but that's the next step :)

Comment: I read your comment 30+ mins after you posted and constructed that code

Comment: good :) now add a condition to limit the # of questions (your q) to less-equal 5 - that's plain java, basically unrelated to fx

Comment: btw, and unrelated to your problem: stick to java naming conventions!